# return values from sql query when ajaxform is applied

Tags: php, jquery

I got a

$.ajax({

```
type: "get",
                    url: "detail.php",
                    data: "iq="+q,
                    success: function() {

                        $('#Title').text('value','');


                    }
```

and a sql query select statement.  I want to return the value from the sql statement to #Title on the php page.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: use single element in **.text()**

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
  $('#Title').text('value',data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this ([`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) takes one argument):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: "detail.php",
  data: { iq: q },
  success: function(data) {
    $('#Title').text(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: @Jean - I don't understand the question, it's a single property...if you want many things you need to put them together like you want, concatenating strings, etc.

Comment: I am calling the value from detail based on the value of iq. So in the detail.php, I write echo $row_xx[''] and echo $row_xx[''].  How do I display these 2 echos?